# Ajax call returns data but in purely string format.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In PHP I can do things like this:

```
echo "<div>".$myvariable."</div>";
```

Which will print out my variable with div's in HTML for its tags. However recently, I needed to do a ajax call using jquery. I'm somewhat familiar with ajax but I don't use it much. Anyways, I run the ajax code, it prints the data into my HMTL element box like I wanted, however, the div tags are printed and displayed along with the content itself!

The entire return data is pretty much 1 long string, rather than the PHP parsing my data like I want it to. Where did I go wrong? Why is it only returning 1 long string?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

$meal = $_POST['meals'];

$meal_q = "SELECT item
              FROM meal_ingredients
              WHERE meal_name='$meal'
              ORDER BY item";

$meal_c = $conn->query($meal_q);
    while ($row = $meal_c->fetch_assoc()){
         $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
         echo "<div>".$view_ingredient."</div>";
    };

?>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
if($('body').hasClass('CreateMealPage')){

    $('tr').on('click', function(e){
        $('#sidebar').animate({right: '-200px'}, 500);
        var meals = $(this).find('.meals').text();

        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: 'meal_list.php',
          data: {meals: meals},
          success: function(data) {
            var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
            sidebar.innerHTML = "";
            sidebar.append(data);
          }
        });
    });

};
```

WHAT IS RENDERED ON SCREEN:

```
<div>ingredientname</div>
<div>ingredientname</div>
<div>ingredientname</div>
```

RATHER THAN:

```
ingredientname
ingredientname
ingredientname
```

Comment: $("#sidebar.append(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: can you paste the service response from network panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace

```
sidebar.innerHTML = "";
sidebar.append(data);
```

with

```
sidebar.innerHTML = data;
```

To answer your comment you can use append with following in jquery

```
$(sidebar).append($(data))
```

so jquery's append needs to be used, instead of append, from dom api, which takes a node element only in arguments. If you still need to use append of dom api, use something like:

```
sidebar.append(document.createRange().createContextualFragme‌​nt(data))
```

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it works. I'm guessing it has something to do with the append function? Thank you. :)

Comment: append takes node element so if you still want to use that you can either use document.createElement api in loop or 

sidebar.append(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data))

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: "html"` to the properties in your `$.ajax()` call, like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: 'meal_list.php',
      dataType: "html",
      data: {meals: meals},
      success: function(data) {
        var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
        sidebar.innerHTML = "";
        sidebar.append(data);
      }
    });
```

This will inform the call to expect HTML data to be returned in the response body.

Comment: I tried this, but it still prints out the div tags as a string.